# Building a Google Calendar-like component with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to build my own weekly calendar component using React and Luxon.

My react component renders an HTML table, each cell represents a Day and time in the day.

I have successfully created events on click of a td using its id, the event creates a child Event component in the td.

However, I am having issues when trying to expand my Event component to occupy extra rows.

1) I have not been able to implement a successful resize functionality on the Event component. I used the 'resize: vertical'css property but when I release the click it goes back to its original size.

2) I still don't know if this would be the correct approach as I dont know if there's a way I can tell react that my resized component now occupies 2+ rows.

3) I am wondering if it's possible to expand the child component over another row and make it adjust to the full height of a new row.

This is my (very unfinished) Component (I am also using Bulma for CSS)

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { DateTime, Duration } from 'luxon'

function Calendar() {

  const startTime = Duration.fromObject({ hours: 8 })
  const endTime = Duration.fromObject({ hours: 20 })
  const start = DateTime.local().startOf('day').plus(startTime)
  const end = DateTime.local().startOf('day').plus(endTime)
  const dur = Duration.fromObject({ minutes: 15 })
  const range = end.diff(start, ['hours']).hours
  const today = DateTime.local()

  // const [cellData, setcellData] = useState()
  const [activeWeek, setactiveWeek] = useState(today.startOf('week'))
  const [events, setevents] = useState({})
  const [month, setmonth] = useState(activeWeek.toLocaleString({ month: 'long', }))

  // const testTime = DateTime.fromMillis(1586438100000)
  // const testDay = DateTime.fromMillis(1586232000000)
  // console.log('time', testTime.c.hour)
  // console.log('day', testDay.plus({ hours: testTime.c.hour, minutes: testTime.c.minute }).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_FULL))


  const getTimeSlots = (start, dur, range) => {
    let slotRange = range * 4
    let arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i <= slotRange; i++) {
      arr = [...arr, {
        formatted: start.toLocaleString(DateTime.TIME_24_SIMPLE),
        date: start
      }]
      start = start.plus(dur)
    }
    return arr
  }

  const getWeekDays = () => {
    let arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      let dayOfWeek = activeWeek.plus({ days: i })

      let dayDisplayFormat = {
        letters: dayOfWeek.toFormat('EEE'),
        number: dayOfWeek.toFormat('dd')
      }
      arr = [...arr, {
        formatted: dayDisplayFormat,
        date: dayOfWeek
      }]
    }
    return arr
  }

  const weekDays = getWeekDays()
  const timeSlots = getTimeSlots(start, dur, range)
  // console.log(timeSlots)


  const handleEntryCreation = (e) => {
    setevents({
      ...events,
      [e.target.id]: {
        date: DateTime.fromFormat(e.target.id, 'EEE dd')
      }
    })
    console.log(events)
  }

  const calculateSlotDate = (day, time) => {
    const slotDate = day.plus({ hours: time.c.hour, minutes: time.c.minute })
    return slotDate
  }

  const handleWeekChange = (action) => {
    action === 'forward' ?
      setactiveWeek(activeWeek.plus({ week: 1 })) :
      setactiveWeek(activeWeek.minus({ week: 1 }))
    setmonth(activeWeek.toLocaleString({ month: 'long', }))
  }

  const Box = () => {
    return (
      <div className="calendarbox-container">
        <div className="calendarbox">
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="calendar">
      <h1 className="title calendar-title">{month}</h1>
      < table className="table is-bordered is-fullwidth" >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th onClick={() => handleWeekChange('back')}>{'<'}</th>
            {weekDays.map((day) => (
              <th key={day.date.ts}>
                {day.formatted.letters}
                <br />
                <span className={
                  today.hasSame(day.date, 'day') ?
                    'calendar-today' :
                    'calendar-notToday'
                }>{day.formatted.number}</span>
              </th>
            ))}
            <th onClick={() => handleWeekChange('forward')}>{'>'}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {timeSlots.map((time) => (
            <tr key={time.date.ts}>
              <td key={`right_${time.date.ts}`}>
                {time.formatted}
              </td>
              {weekDays.map((day) => {
                const slotValue = calculateSlotDate(day.date, time.date)
                return (
                  <td
                    key={slotValue.toMillis()}
                    id={slotValue.toMillis()}
                    onClick={handleEntryCreation}
                  >
                    {events[slotValue.toMillis()] ?
                      <Box /> :
                      null
                    }

                  </td>
                )
              })}
              <td key={`left_${time.date.ts}`}>{time.formatted}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table >
    </div>
  )
}

export default Calendar
```

```css
.calendar {
  td {
    &:hover {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0.25rem;
    border-left: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    // user-select: none;
  }
  tr {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    // height: 50px;
    // align-items: center;
  }
  th {
    text-align: center !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
    user-select: none;
  }
  table {
    // table-layout: fixed;
  }
  &-title {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
  }
  &-today {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
  }
  &-notToday {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
  }
}

.calendarbox {
  &-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    // position: relative;
    z-index: 60;
  }
  // position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  resize: vertical !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you show us your working code?

Comment: What you want to do is similar to full-calender library:https://fullcalendar.io/   you can  check thier source code